# Calling startActivity(intent) doesn't recreate the Activity

Tags: android

When my app is started, the HomepageActivity gets created. There is another activity, Activity2, that the user can navigate to at any point.

From Activity2, I create an Intent to open HomepageActivity with some data and call `startActivity(intent)`. This Intent data is needed to set some data for the HomepageActivity's Fragment in `Fragment.onCreate` but after calling startActivity, the HomepageActivity does not get recreated. It simply calls `onResume` and the fragment does not get the data from the intent.

From debugging, the intent does contain the correct data in `onResume` but it doesn't make sense to check the intent every time `onResume` is called. How can I recreate HomepageActivity or otherwise pass data to it if it is already created?

Comment: There is another method [onNewIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) which will be called if the Activity is not recreated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your problem.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);// restarts the activity
startActivity(intent);
```